# using air pressure as a liquid pump

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pressure-vessel, foundations, masonry

I have a $100\ \text{psi}, 300\ \text{cfm}$ air compressor that we use for running power tools, I need a way to inject mortar deep into a small opening and was wondering if anyone had experience with setups like this.  From doing some research on the topic it sounds like historically it's pretty much what they did before the specialized concrete pumps we have now were around.  I'm not worried about air mixing with the mortar but it would be interesting to know how much force this would have on the person at the operating end of the hose.  I can't see it being more than a fire hose as long as we stick to a relatively small hose (the air input is $1"$ and I was planning on $1/2"$ for the output hose)  All fittings and hoses are rated for $150\ \text{psi}$ and I was planning on buying a $200\ \text{psi}$ rated pressure tank.  Am I missing anything here?

*edit* Just in case someone wanted to see my math here, I used the the following numbers 
density of (flowable grout) $= 128.7 \ \text{lbs/ft}^3 = 2061.6 \ \text{kg/m}^3$ 
Operating pressure $= 100\ \text{psi} = 689.476\ \text{kN/m}^2$

using $P =\rho*g*h$, we get $689476 = 2.0616*9.85*h$, where $h=\frac{689476}{2061.6*9.85} = 34\ \text{m}$ of pressure $= 111\ \text{ft}$ of available head (minus what's lost from friction with the hose/pipe/fittings) 
Should still be plenty enough pressure for what I need though also pressure at the nozzle would be $\frac{100}{0.7853} = 127.3\ \text{lbs}$, probably gonna bump that hose up to $3/4"$

[image: Rough drawing of setup]

*edit* - Drawing explanation
As addressed in the comments I was just going to use ball valves at the grout intake air inlet and grout outlet, the pressure tanks I was looking at were 200 PSI 5 gallon water tanks that have like 8 ports already built into them.  The mortar works out to about 4.7 gallons of flowable mortar/40# bag so it should work out for the smaller jobs we'd be using it for.

Comment: You should put your math into your original question - save people having to trawl through comments.

Comment: The gravity feed - will that pressure exceed the pressure inside the tank? or else it gets blown back up...

Comment: Gravity feed could have a checkvalve inline - you wouldn't be able to feed in while the compressor was running, but could pump in batches

Comment: Can you explain your drawing? if the air pressure isn't applied "behind" the mortar flow, it won't do anything useful.  If all you want to do is empty the hole of "liquid" then use a vacuuum cleaner system to do so before pouring mortar.

Comment: I understood the container in the drawing to be a storage tank, not the 'hole'

Comment: so the image would make more sense with the grout outlet coming from the bottom of the cylinder but I didn't realize that was an option till after I drew it and was looking at the standard porting on some tanks.  Basically the work process would go like this, fire up generator and mix a 40# bag of grout mix with enough water to get it in the flowable but not liquid stage.  With all three pipe valves closed open the grout intake first and insert mixed batch into the cylinder and close the grout intake valve.  Open the compressor air intake valve and allow pressure to max out at 100 psi or less

Comment: depending on results of the first few batches, there'd be a regulator we could adjust that's already inline for other tools used with the compressor system.  Once pressure equalizes insert the end of the grout nozzle where you want the grout to go and open the grout outlet valve.  With both the air inlet and grout outlet valve open the system would "pump" the grout into the nooks and crannies we need to pack it into but are hard to reach or get tools into.

I'd include a 100 psi pressure release valve at the tank and between the tank and operator for safety

Comment: I guess one other question I had was does anyone know what type of valves would be most economical for this?  I was just going to use standard ball valves due to accessibility, but I'm thinking the grittiness of the grout could potentially cause them to malfunction and potentially leave us either replacing them or unable to close them mid job.

Comment: Sure not clear to me where in inject mortar come into this.

Comment: I'd consider negative pressure using a pipe as an atomizer by blowing air horizontally over the upper end of the vertical pipe whilst grout is poured into holes. It would work rather like a vacuum cleaner sucking the mortar into the hole

Answer (score 0):

I would look at an auger extruder system like I've sketched out. They're good for extruding abrasive pastes like ceramics, mortar or grout. When the motor turns, the mortar would flow, when it stops flow stops.
[image: Crappy sketch of auger extruder]